# Determine dependency between .NET projects

Tags: .net, dependencies, dependency-management

We have a big and complex application composed by at least 700 DLL. The number is growing month after month. The code is not well structured because every DLL is a stand alone solutions. As you can imagine, when have some problem when we have to test a new feature on a DLL because we do not know exactly where it is used.

I am thinking to write a program that scan the file system, open the solution XML file and create a graph that contain all the references.

Is it a good idea?
Do you have some other solutions?

Comment: [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) (they aren't paying me to say that ;))

Comment: It's quite trivial to write such a tool (simply reading the solution files); I wrote something like this some years ago to track some circular dependencies in a messy and complex application.

Comment: @gnat: can any of those dependency management systems create a dependency graph of an existing project? If not, then this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Is your application under one .NET solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try to consolidate those dlls. Do you have a class per dll or something?! 
Combine related functionality currently contained within lots of dlls into a single dll, then you can start to get a grasp on your dependency chain. 700 is just too many to manage well.

Comment: Our system, our developers, out time and our business make this job not possible. I agree with you, but the scenario is pretty difficult

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have some other solutions?

**In short:** Combine your code under **one solution** and define project dependencies their.

Having so many `dlls` is troublesome for maintenance and further development. If you have the source code, I would suggest de-compile this dlls to their own small projects and **combine them under one solution**. It would be much clear and easier to manage dependencies from their on.

However, all that re-organizational work would cost you time of a developer who understands the system very well.